# Select Next Login Time for User

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called [Session]

```
|SessionId | UserId | StartDate| EndDate |

|    1     |    1   | 09:00     |  11:00 |
|    2     |    2   | 09:10     |  11:10 |
|    2     |    1   | 11:20     |  15:00 |
```

How do i return the results of this table with an extra column called NextStart Date for each user? So in the Above example the top row will return

```
|SessionId | UserId | StartDate| EndDate | NextStartDate

|    1     |    1   | 09:00     |  11:00 | 11:20
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql). Unless you're still on a pre-2012 version.

Comment: Express 2014, thanks will check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use LEAD

```
select SessionID, 
       UserId, 
       StartDate, 
       EndDate, 
       lead(StartDate) over(partition by UserID order by StartDate) as NextStartDate
from MyTable
```

Note, this will not account for any crossovers and will return the next startdate for the user regardless of whether an enddate occured between them

Comment: Can you give a hint how to get the next start after the end Date ?